# Can you publish as a natural person/anonymously/pseudoanonymously under Business Source License(BSL 1.1)?

Tags: business

My question is, can you publish the code under Business Source License(BSL 1.1) as a:

```
1.) Natural person(not a registered company)
2.) Anonymous (Pseudoanonymously)
```

To sum up; Can I publish the code licensed via BSL 1.1 under the pseudonym as a natural person(not a registered company)?

BSL 1.1 for reference;
https://mariadb.com/bsl11/

Would the copyright be still valid if the licensor is a pseudonym and the owner of the pseudonym is a natural person (not a company)? Of course under the assumption, you could later prove you are the rightful owner of the license/ you were the one behind the pseudonym.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "The Business Source License (this document, or the “License”) is not an Open Source license."

Comment: It becomes open source after a period of time(max 4 years). Prevents commercial abuse in this period of time. Seems relevant.

Comment: @smenir443 it's not.  We're clear in our [help text](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what's on-topic here. Understanding, applying, and complying with non-free licences isn't listed, and we're clear about the criteria we use to determine whether something is free - and a licence that doesn't give you the four freedoms for four years isn't free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would the copyright be still valid if the licensor is a pseudonym and the owner of the pseudonym is a natural person(not company)?

Yes. The validity of a copyright claim is not dependent on the license that is used, but only on what the copyright law in the relevant jurisdiction states.
Fortunately, the Berne convention has largely harmonized the copyright laws in the signatory countries (which is nearly all countries in the world).

Copyright can be held anonymously or under a pseudonym by natural persons.

> Can i publish the code licensed via BSL 1.1 under the pseudonym as a natural person(not a registered company)?

Yes. The BSL license does not restrict in any way who can apply the license to their work.